# Launch image not shown for iPhone on landscape only app

Tags: ios, landscape, universal, splash-screen, launchimage

App details are as follows: Universal landscape only app. iOS version iOS 8 onwards. Splash screen loads on iPad but is not loaded on iPhone. Also warning is shown for iPhone 4inch retina image. But asset catalog with iOS 8 and landscape option selected does not have provision to add iPhone 4 retina image. Please assist.